# Funding for Government Run Space Organizations

Tags: nasa, cost, space-agencies

Do government run space organizations make any money from services they provide (for example NASA's data about the Earth or their services for aviation companies)?
Or do they provide all their services for free and **just** get funding from the government?

Comment: It would be nice to get a general overview of the money flow around NASA - like where does the money from commercial launches go? What if NASA generated a surplus?

Comment: "What if NASA generated a surplus?" If only, my friend. If only.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yeah, I know, such unrealistic sci-fi scenarios aren't much on-topic here.

Comment: Note that they don't *just* get funding; the money is earmarked for specific purposes (budgets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for example, NASA does collect money from licensing [patents](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-offers-licenses-of-patented-technologies-to-start-up-companies). As Organic Marble hints in the comments, NASA does not turn a profit. Even if they could, this is not the purpose of NASA.